# Android: How to change TextColor with a conditional statement

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, textcolor

I'm trying to make a simple people counter app where the buttons will increment/decrement the amount of people. I'm trying to make a conditional that if the number of people (count) exceeds 15, make the text red. I tried to do text_name!!.setTextColor(Color.Red), but it doesn't seem to work with that. I attached the files in my project. I am making the app under MVP architecture.

Contract.kt

```
package com.example.peoplecounter

import android.graphics.Color

interface Contract {
    interface View {
        fun setCount(count: String)
        fun setTotalCount(count: String)
        fun changeTextColor()
        fun hideButton()
        fun viewButton()

    }

    interface Model {
        fun getCount(): String
        fun getFlag(): Boolean
       // fun getZeroFlag() : Boolean
        fun getTotalCount(): String
        fun reset()
        fun inc()
        fun decr()
        //fun Zero()

    }

    interface Presenter {
        fun onAddCountButtonPressed()
        fun onMinusCountButtonPressed()
        fun onResetButtonPressed()
        fun onOverCapacity()
        fun isZero()
        fun getCount() :Int
    }
}
```

Model.kt

```
class Model : Contract.Model {
    private var count = 0
    private var totalCount = 0
    private var overcapacity = false
    //private var isZero = false

    override fun getCount(): String = count.toString()
    override fun getFlag(): Boolean = overcapacity
    override fun getTotalCount(): String = totalCount.toString()
   // override fun getZeroFlag() : Boolean = isZero

    override fun reset() {
        count = 0
        totalCount = 0
    }

    override fun inc() {
        count += 1
        totalCount += 1
        if(count > 15){
            overcapacity = true;
        }

    }

    override fun decr() {
        count -= 1
        if(count<0){
            count = 0
        }
    }


}
```

Presenter.kt

```
package com.example.peoplecounter

import com.example.peoplecounter.Contract

class Presenter (private val model: Contract.Model, private val view: Contract.View): Contract.Presenter {

    override fun onAddCountButtonPressed() {
        model.inc()
        view.setCount(model.getCount())
        view.setTotalCount(model.getTotalCount())
    }

    override fun onMinusCountButtonPressed() {
        model.decr()
        view.setCount(model.getCount())
    }

    override fun onResetButtonPressed() {
        model.reset()
        view.setCount(model.getCount())
        view.setTotalCount(model.getTotalCount())
    }

    override fun onOverCapacity(){
        if(model.getFlag() == true){
            view.changeTextColor()
        }
    }

    override fun isZero(){
        if(Integer.parseInt(model.getCount())  == 0){
            view.hideButton();
        }
        else{
            view.viewButton();
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return Integer.parseInt(model.getCount())
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.peoplecounter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Contract.View {
    private lateinit var presenter: Contract.Presenter
    private var peoplecount: TextView? = null
    private var totalcount: TextView? = null
    private var plusbutton: Button? = null
    private var minusbutton: Button? = null
    private var resetbutton: Button? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        peoplecount = findViewById(R.id.people_count_number)
        totalcount = findViewById(R.id.total_number_text)
        plusbutton = findViewById(R.id.increment_button)
        minusbutton = findViewById(R.id.decrement_button)
        resetbutton = findViewById(R.id.reset_button)

        presenter = Presenter(Model(), this)
        setOnClickListeners()
        presenter.isZero()
        presenter.onOverCapacity()
    }

    private fun setOnClickListeners() {
        plusbutton!!.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onAddCountButtonPressed()
        }
        minusbutton!!.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onMinusCountButtonPressed()
        }
        resetbutton!!.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onResetButtonPressed()
        }
    }


    override fun setCount(count: String) {
        people_count_number!!.text = count
    }

    override fun setTotalCount(count: String) {
        total_number_text!!.text = count
    }

    override fun changeTextColor() {
        people_count!!.setTextColor(Color.CYAN)
        people_count_number!!.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    }

    override fun hideButton() {
        decrement_button?.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun viewButton() {
        decrement_button?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Total: "
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_number_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reset_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:text="RESET"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/people_count_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/people_count"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/people_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=" People"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.kronplatz"
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decrement_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increment_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The methods we are focusing on are OnOverCapacity() in Presenter.kt, changeTextColor() in MainActivity.kt, and getFlag() in Model.kt

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put `onOverCapacity()` inside function `onAddCountButtonPressed()`, if it exceeds 15, then proceed to call `onOverCapacity()`, i.e.

```
override fun onAddCountButtonPressed() {
   ...
   ...
   ...
   if (model.getCount() > 15) {
      onOverCapacity()
   }
}
```

and also, I think you need to call a function to restore the color if by any chance you reset the count, or minus the count and the count is not exceeds 15

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. Another question for you if you are able to figured out how to save the state of the app after closure? I tried using SharedPreferences but I dont think I'm implementing it right.

Comment: Well, it depends on the needs for persisting data after apps killed, should go for SharedPreferences, or use Room if it needs quite amount of data. It seems in your case, if only to save the count value, SharedPreferences is a preferred one